# strange inheritance in ruby mixins

Tags: ruby, module, mixins

I am wondering, why is an included module's methods mixed in to any subsequent class definitions (as if the class included it in itself)?

```
module Foo
  def bar
    print "#{self}\n"
  end
end

class Bar
end

begin
  Bar.bar
rescue NoMethodError
  puts "There is no Bar.bar\n"
end

include Foo

bar
Bar.bar
Bar.new.bar
```

prints:

```
There is no Bar.bar
main
Bar
#<Bar:0xb73f2048>
```

Is this the expected behavior? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you include Foo in your program but outside of any class or method then it is included in to the current scope which is the `main` object.

You could test this by modifying your bar method to the following

```
  def bar
    print "InBar class: #{self.class} value: #{self}\n"
  end
```

And then adding the following 2 lines at the end

```
2.bar
Fixnum.bar
```

This would give you the following output

```
There is no Bar.bar
InBar class: Object value: main
InBar class: Class value: Bar
InBar class: Bar value: #<Bar:0x21ecec>
InBar class: Fixnum value: 2
InBar class: Class value: Fixnum
```

Comment: `main` actually isn't a class it's an object. As such `include` shouldn't (strictly) be available at top-level. Nonetheless `include` is made available as a special case (convenience method) but it's behaviour is to mix the module into `Object`

Comment: @banister. Thanks fingers faster than brain. Edited appropriately

Answer (score 2):

an `include` at top-level mixes the module into `Object`. In so far as it's mixed into `Object` it's available as an instance method on everything.